# How to use setCompoundDrawables with Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I've been struggling with a specific line of code for quite a long time. Here it is:

```
btnForward.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMediaPlay,0);
```

Whenever this line is called my app crashes and my app output states the following:

> [mono-rt] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getDrawable' signature='(I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;' in class Landroid/content/Context;
>   [mono-rt]   at com.enterprise.project.CallDetails.n_onCreate(Native Method)
>   [mono-rt]   at com.enterprise.project.CallDetails.onCreate(CallDetails.java:29)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   [mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   [mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   [mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   [mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   [mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   [mono-rt]   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I tried multiple variants of the SetCompoundDrawables (intrinsicbound, relative, etc...) but since many other threads said that WithIntrinsicBounds was the way to go I followed that way.

I've tried using the other variant of the SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (using null instead of 0 and a Drawable instead of an ID) but the same problem comes up.

In case it might be the problem, here are the few lines of code used in the block before the bug

```
        case CallStatus.Paused: //Started but paused
            btnForward.Text = "Complete";
            btnForward.Clickable = true;
            btnForward.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            btnForward.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb (30, 118, 121));
            btnForward.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMediaPlay,0);
            break;
```

Comment: Are you aware about API's levels?

Comment: Xamarin? Android? My Android target is 14. Should I up it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inner your activity:

First retrieve resource id:

```
_flagResourceId = this.Resources.GetIdentifier ("IcMediaPlay", "drawable", this.PackageName);
```

Then set drawable:

```
btnForward.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,Resources.GetDrawable(_flagResourceId),0); Resources.GetDrawable (_flagResourceId)
```